# Write more than 100000 records to the CSV or XLS sheet using apex

Tags: salesforce, large-data, visualforce, apex, force.com

we have requirement :

- To show object data on Visual Force page using pagination.
- Export button to export all records to xls or csv file.

Issue is data size is too large i.e. more than 100000 records.
How can we write more than 100000 records to xls file using Apex?

Comment: VFPage RenderAs, ContentVersion, Tried with standardcontroller pagination but it doesn't support that history object.

Answer (score 0):

I know for sure writing to a 'Document' could work. Maybe even the newer Files feature. You can write and append to an existing document. Using the @read only annotation you can query more than 10.000 records. You might run into heap size errors though. Other option could be to use the Bulk API v2.